# What is the right way to pass component props in Vue3 tests that use Vuetify components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vue-test-utils

I am trying to write a basic unit test for a component called CompanyBioPanel. Here is a simplified version of the component:

```
// template

    <v-card-text>
      <v-tabs v-model="companyTabs">
        <v-tab value="generalData">
          <h2>Details</h2>
        </v-tab>
        <v-tab value="companyConfiguration">
          <h2>Company Configuration</h2>
        </v-tab>
      </v-tabs>
      <v-divider />
      <v-window
        v-if="companyData.company_id != null"
        v-model="companyTabs"
      >
        <v-window-item value="generalData">
          <v-list>
            <company-data-item
              v-for="item in generalData"
              :key="item.label"
              :label="item.label"
              :value="item.value"
            />
          </v-list>
        </v-window-item>
        <v-window-item value="companyConfiguration">
          <v-list>
            <company-data-item
              v-for="item in companyConfiguration"
              :key="item.label"
              :label="item.label"
              :value="item.value"
            />
          </v-list>
        </v-window-item>
      </v-window>
    </v-card-text>

// script
import type { Company } from './types'
import {
  computed,
  toRefs,
  ref,
  type ComputedRef
} from 'vue'
import CompanyDataItem from './CompanyDataItem.vue'

const props = defineProps<{ companyData: { [key: string]: string } }>()

const companyTabs = ref(null)

const { companyData } = toRefs(props)

const companyIdOrNull = computed(() => {
  return companyData.value?.company_id ?? null
})

const generalData: ComputedRef<CompanyDataItemProps[]> = computed(() => {
  if (companyData.value == null) {
    return []
  }

  return [
    {
      label: 'Name',
      value: companyData.value.name,
      fieldName: 'name',
      isEditable: true
    }
  ]
})
```

In my test, I would like to assert that when I pass the `companyData` object as a prop to my component, it renders the `company-data-item` component.

Here is my test:

```
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import { h } from 'vue'
import { VApp } from 'vuetify/components'
import CompanyBioPanel from './CompanyBioPanel.vue'

it('renders the company bio panel', async () => {
  const companyData = {
    company_id: 'abc',
    name: 'Test Company'
  }

  const wrapper = mount(VApp, { slots: { default: h(CompanyBioPanel, { props: { companyData } }) } })

  expect(wrapper.exists()).toBe(true)
  const html = wrapper.html()
  expect(html).toContain('Test Company')

  const companyName = wrapper.find('h1')
  expect(companyName.text()).toBe('Test Company')

  const companyDataItems = wrapper.findAllComponents({ name: 'company-data-item' })
  expect(companyDataItems.length).toBe(1)
})
```

This is a simple test asserting that child components are generated from data passed as props. However, I get the following error when I attempt to run my test:

```
⎯⎯⎯ Failed Tests 1 ⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯

 FAIL  src/components/company-view/company-bio-panel/CompanyBioPanel.test.ts > renders the company bio panel
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'company_id')
 ❯ src/components/company-view/company-bio-panel/CompanyBioPanel.vue:45:27
     43|       <v-divider />
     44|       <v-window
     45|         v-if="companyData.company_id != null"
       |                           ^
     46|         v-model="companyTabs"
     47|       >
```

This doesn't make sense to me, because I am passing the props in my test, so how could `companyData` be `undefined`?

I've also tried modifying the way I pass props to be like this:

```
  const wrapper = mount(VApp, { slots: { default: h(CompanyBioPanel, { companyData }) } })
```

but that leads to an even stranger error:

```
⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯ Unhandled Errors ⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯

Vitest caught 1 unhandled error during the test run.
This might cause false positive tests. Resolve unhandled errors to make sure your tests are not affected.

⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯ Unhandled Rejection ⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯
TypeError: Cannot create property '_destroyed' on number '-1'
 ❯ clearImmediate node:timers:325:24
 ❯ GlobalWindow.cancelAnimationFrame ../../node_modules/happy-dom/src/window/Window.ts:921:10
 ❯ node_modules/vuetify/lib/components/VSlideGroup/VSlideGroup.mjs:104:9
 ❯ callWithErrorHandling ../../node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:156:18
 ❯ callWithAsyncErrorHandling ../../node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:164:17
 ❯ job ../../node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:1831:9
 ❯ flushPreFlushCbs ../../node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:308:7
 ❯ updateComponentPreRender ../../node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:5876:5
 ❯ ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] ../../node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:5794:11
 ❯ ReactiveEffect.run ../../node_modules/@vue/reactivity/dist/reactivity.cjs.js:182:19
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a Vuetify instance :

```
const vuetify = createVuetify()
```

And Use mount with global.plugins to properly integrate Vuetify;

```
const wrapper = mount(VApp, { 
    global: {
      plugins: [vuetify],
    },
    slots: {
      default: () => h(CompanyBioPanel, { companyData }) // Correctly passing props
    } 
  })
```

And then if you wait for the next DOM update this will ensure all asynchronous updates have been processed before making assertions.
:

```
await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();
```

And this should pass the props correctly

Comment: Thanks for your answer, with your example I get that UnhandledRejection error, so I guess it must be a bug with Vuetify or something. I'll keep digging.